# iOS: Have UIImagePickerController be the first view using storyboards

Tags: ios

I'm building an app where the first view needs to be the picture taking view using UIImagePickerController.

I am able to put a button on the screen and have it load the view when pressed, but how do you make it the initial view that loads? Basically load with out user interaction.

I'm using storyboards and I think the lack of knowledge of how they exactly work is my problem.

Comment: So you've got some code that behaves correctly on button press? If that's the case, move the code in the button handler into your view controllers viewWillAppear method.

Comment: have you tried to initialize UIImagePickerController in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I tried viewDidLoad, but when you do [self presentSomething] says that the view( self ) doesn't exist yet. I bet the viewWillAppear suggested above would work. Forgot about that method.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIImagePickerController in your rootviewcontroller.

```
@interface MyRootViewController : UIImagePickerController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods won't work. I think you may have to put it in

```
    -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
           [self presentSomething]; 
    }
```

There will be a second where you'll just see the viewController before the image picker will come up. Best to account for this by making sure there's a background that's pleasant for that split second.